# PHP - How group items within array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've been trying to group items within an array for quite some time now. You know when you post images on Facebook and they group together in one post if they're uploaded within x minutes apart form each other? This is what I want to achieve.

Backend solution: Each time a user posts an image to a certain event, and entry in the "newsfeed" table gets created with a pointer (id) to the upload's row id in another table. The php script then grabs all posts separately and puts them in an array.

Now, given that I know how to measure the difference in time between two created dates, how do I go about sorting the arrays so each entry in the array contains the images that where x minutes apart from each other by upload date instead of separate?

Thanks in advance!

The code I've got so far is close to this solution but it still adds item to the final array for each single image post. You can see the results of this here:

[image: image of result]

As you can see the bottom three posts are supposed to be all in the same post since they are uploaded within 10 minutes apart from each other. The topmost of those three is looking like the result I want, but there's 2 following posts which seem to be added as separate steps as the foreach iterates. How can I make my "algorithm" ignore those? The code, at least in my head when looking at it, should do the job.

```
$newsfeed = array();
$event_uploads = array();

foreach ($get_newsfeed as $item) {
    if ($item["type"]["id"] == 5) {

        $query = "select * from event_album_uploads where id = ". $item["text"];
        $get_event_upload = $db->query($query);

        foreach ($get_event_upload as $event_upload) {
            if (empty($event_uploads)) {

                $item["images"] = array("0" => $event_upload);
                array_push($event_uploads, $item);

            } else {

                foreach ($event_uploads as $key => $upload) {
                    if ($item["item_id"] == $upload["item_id"] && $item["other_id"] == $upload["other_id"]) {

                        $itemDate = new DateTime($item["date"]);
                        $uploadDate = new DateTime($upload["date"]);
                        $difference = $uploadDate->diff($itemDate);

                        if ($difference->i < 10) {
                            $images = $event_uploads[$key]["images"];
                            array_push($images, $event_upload);
                            $event_uploads[$key]["images"] = $images;
                        } else {
                            $item["images"] = array("0" => $event_upload);
                            array_push($event_uploads, $item);
                        }

                    } else {
                        $item["images"] = array("0" => $event_upload);
                        array_push($event_uploads, $item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        array_push($newsfeed, $item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a combination of `usort()` and `strtotime()`? Not enough actual code/data to work with. Just guess at this point.

Comment: @Rasclatt I've updated the post description, adding the loop in question and an image of the result.